# join produced number convert to int

Tags: python, join

Example:

```
import re
rx = re.compile("{0-9}")
Var1 =bla bla bla 54467
Var2= rx.findall(Var1)
number = ''.join(Var2)
```

My question is how to convert the number variable to int, i try to do so with int() but i get an error.
Or is there a way to create such a variable as int with another method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions for this.  `filter()` is uch easier and quicker:

```
>>> s = "bla bla bla 54467 bla"
>>> int(filter(str.isdigit, s))
54467
```

The above code will merge all numbers in the string into a single string.  If you don't want this, use

```
>>> s = "bla 1223 bla 54467 bla"
>>> map(int, filter(str.isdigit, s.split()))
[1223, 54467]
```

The same recipes adapted for Python 3.x are:

```
>>> s = "bla bla bla 54467 bla"
>>> int("".join(filter(str.isdigit, s)))
54467
>>> s = "bla 1223 bla 54467 bla"
>>> list(map(int, filter(str.isdigit, s.split())))
[1223, 54467]
```

Comment: the map function give me other output not like you have here. it gives me that output: <map object at 0x1beb250>. i wanna get the output you have here, how ?

Comment: and the int() as you write it here doesn't work either, it give me an error that it doesn't like to convert filter .

Comment: @HananN.: My solution is for Python 2.x.  You didn't say you are using Python 3.x, and 95 % of the users are still using 2.x.

Comment: Updated my answer with the 3.x variants.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex is wrong. The following works:

```
import re
rx = re.compile("[0-9]") # note the change
Var1 ='bla bla bla 54467 bla'
Var2= rx.findall(Var1)
number = int(''.join(Var2))
print number
```

Note that the above code will find all digits inside the string, regardless of whether they're consecutive, and merge them into a single number. To get groups of consecutive digits, change your regex to `"[0-9]+"`.